# After so much travel and research, why did Newt Scamander write such a simple book which lacks details?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

Newt Scamander has researched a lot on magical creatures and yet if you compare his book *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* with Darwin's books, it'd look nothing.

Why did Newt Scamander write such a simple book which doesn't even have those details which Newt Scamander knew in *Fantastic Beasts* movie series?

Comment: Because the real FB was written in a few days for a charity auction

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## The version we see is written for Muggles.

The two versions of Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them available for purchase are both written for Muggles.

> “This edition, however, has a loftier purpose than the instruction of the wizarding community. For the first time in the history of the noble publishing house of Obscurus, one of its titles is to be made available to Muggles.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

They’re for Muggles to read while still having the Muggles believe that the creatures described in it are fictional, so presumably the Muggle editions would be less detailed than the editions sold exclusively to wizards and never seen by Muggles.

> “I would like to take this opportunity to reassure Muggle purchasers that the amusing creatures described hereafter are fictional and cannot hurt you. To wizards, I say merely: *Draco dormiens nunquam titillandus.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

Since Muggles are still supposed to not believe in the creatures written about, it’s very likely certain details would be left out, and the descriptions wouldn’t be as in-depth as in the editions for wizards. It’d be wise to leave out any ways of catching these creatures or particularly specific locations where any of them are found, lest any curious Muggles try to find them, leading to violations of Clause 73 of the International Code of Wizarding Secrecy.

> “In 1750, Clause 73 was inserted in the International Code of Wizarding Secrecy, to which wizard ministries worldwide conform today:
>
> Each wizarding governing body will be responsible for the concealment, care, and control of all magical beasts, beings, and spirits dwelling within its territory’s borders. Should any such creature cause harm to, or draw the notice of, the Muggle community, that nation’s wizarding governing body will be subject to discipline by the International Confederation of Wizards.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

It’s logical that the version of this wizarding book that’s made available to Muggles would include less information than the wizards’ editions, since giving Muggles too much knowledge about magical creatures would be a danger to magic remaining secret. As Valorum mentions in the comments, the copies of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* seen at Newt’s book launch are at least double the size of the Muggle version.

[image]

The version seen at Newt’s book launch is also clearly shown to be much larger than the Muggle editions in the Flourish and Blotts advertisement for it.

[image]

Therefore, it seems clear that the versions of *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* that’s sold exclusively to wizards contains more information than the Muggle editions.

Comment: It's also possible we only see the version of Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them that's suitable for pupils at Hogwarts. When studied Geology as an undergraduate we had a book called An Introduction to the Rock Forming Minerals by Deere, Howie and Zussman it's a quite thick single volume book. There is another work by Deere, Howie and Zussman that's an Eleven volume set called Rock Forming Minerals.

Comment: The version we see on display during the book opening at Flourish and Blotts is at least double the size of the muggle copy; https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l0rg.gif

Comment: @Sarriesfan Let me guess, there also a 100 volume set called Advanced Rock Forming Minerals by the same authors? I'm starting to see a pattern here :-D

Comment: Also, JK Rowling is not a naturalist. It's one thing to paint a relatively shallow picture of a world in order to tell a story. It's another to be able to provide an insane depth of understanding, history and interconnectivity of a kind of beast. To say nothing of scores of different kinds!

Comment: The edition published in 2001 is indeed billed as a Muggle edition. However, the edition published in 2017 has several notes indicating that it is supposed be the wizards edition, yet while it has several additional entries it has no additional detail. It is also about twice the size of the 2001 edition.